# How do frameworks get images/css that is outside web root

Tags: php

Some web frameworks and CMS allows Users to build their themes, where a css/ folder exists in the theme/ folder and often is outside the web root, how do they retrieve them, as it isn't possible to read css files without the web root?

One solution is Alias in Apache mod_rewrite, but **what is a more PHP generalised solution, especially in a MVC context?**

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>

    Alias /images/ "/User/Public_html/Image/"

    <Directory "/User/Public_html/Image">
        Options Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</IfModule>


theme/
css/
  test.css
view/
  test.html
```

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/test.css">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The theme/ folder outside the web root. So how can I load the CSS file ? I am not interested in aliasing or moving the folder structure to the web root, as it  should be consistent a "theme", and it's in a web MVC context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is a more PHP generalised solution, especially in a MVC context?

For resources that are linked within your application, you can use an internal link-scheme. When the templates / views are processed then, those links can be handled and transformed to working hypertext links (by a filter that can resolve those) so that the client can request from your server as if those were standard HTML links (http(s) scheme).

As the internal link scheme can follow it's own rules it's easy to handle within a frontend-controller that takes care of delivering the response.

***Edit/Differentiation:***

It's perhaps wrong to choose a different URL-Scheme. Not that it won't work, but in context of Hypertext applications - which you speak about - it's perhaps more wise to make use of the *Authority* here (see [*Authority in RFC 3986, Section 3.2.*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2)) so that modules can still specify the target URI scheme (or provide a [*relative reference*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2)) so that the application is more flexible in terms of protocols.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a proxy script that grabs file data from below the web root. For instance you would have the `href` attribute of your `<link />` tag set to a server-side script with a query-string parameter to designate which file should be retrieved. Then the proxy script would read the data and get the correct script, outputting a CSS file. You can even send a `Content-type` header in your proxy script to designate the output as CSS for the browser.

A word of warning. Don't just openly allow any parameter to be passed with this method. White-list what you actually want to be passed as this could be a potential pressure-point for attacks. For instance you don't want people to be able to request your `web.config` or `.htaccess` files.

This method I found to be useful when users had specific style-sheets, so no user could access another user's styles.

Comment: We do something very similar in a Java app to access federated pages, with the appropriate checks in place, works great. Highly recommend this solution.